# What happens if I purchase a building halfway through construction?

Tags: civilization-5, civilization-5-gods-and-kings

If I purchase a building that is halfway through construction, what happens to the extra production?  Is the cost of purchasing the building lowered?  Do I receive a cash payment, similar to an opponent finishing a wonder I was building?  Or does the production just disappear?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You pay the full purchase price and lose the in-progress production. There are no refunds, discounts, or benefits.

So, you generally want to avoid buying buildings that you have mostly completed.

For units, buying a unit has no effect on the in-progress production.

Comment: The same applies to units, even though you can build them more than once.

Comment: @Lawton - see recent edit. Your comment appears false.