# Is purchasing a building you've partly built wasteful?

Tags: civilization-5

If you're partly built a building, and then you purchase it, you still have to pay full price (unlike earlier versions of Civilization).

Is the build input lost, or is it refunded somehow, similar to the cash refund you're given if someone else builds a Wonder before you?

Does the same thing happen when you remove a partly built job (whether it's a unit, building or Wonder) from the build queue?

Comment: [Answer for buildings is here.](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/126067/what-happens-if-i-purchase-a-building-halfway-through-construction?rq=1) I haven't recently tested for units, but my vague memory is that if your purchase a unit, you continue the in-progress production of whatever you are building.

Comment: @AaronKurtzhals thanks I hadn't found that question, this can be closed as a duplicate of it, since I was interested in buildings (I've just tweaked the question to be specific to buildings)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will not get any refund in any way for those hammers. They can be considered to be wasted if you buy the building/unit you have partially built.

Answer (score 1):

The answer *technically* is **YES**. You will waste precious production points accumulated to the turns passed. You will not get a refund on purchasing something you've partly built.

Regarding the build input and refund, the answer lies in [this post](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/126105/how-to-calculate-gold-earned-from-a-wonder-if-another-civilization-finishes-firs).

Just tested this in a hot-seat game. Wonder fail-gold is 1 for 1. That is, you get 1 gold for every hammer input. This is a better return than the 1 gold for 4 hammers you get by building wealth.

Additionally, I checked the source code (Steam -> Tools -> Sid Meier's Civilization V SDK)
For Brave New World, in

```
...\steamapps\common\Sid Meier's Civilization V SDK\CvGameCoreSource\CvGameCoreDLL_Expansion2\CvCity.cpp
```

The relevant code block starts at line 12739 (function CvCity::doCheckProduction)

```
...
iProductionGold = ((iBuildingProduction * iMaxedBuildingGoldPercent) / 100);
...
thisPlayer.GetTreasury()->ChangeGold(iProductionGold);
```

**iMaxedBuildingGoldPercent** is 100, sourced from `GlobalDefines.xml`, for BNW found at

```
...\steamapps\common\sid meier's civilization v\assets\DLC\Expansion2\Gameplay\XML\GlobalDefines.xml
```

Comment: So you get a refund at the end of your turn if you buy a partly constructed building?

Comment: No. Wait, let me edit my answer. That is why you are just wasting the production (hammer).

Comment: The answer you've quoted refers to Wonders, I'm interested in buildings

Comment: That is right. But still answer your question on the 1st part though.:)